# Linking errors undefined vtable and typeinfo

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, virtual-functions

I get this error:

```
Undefined                     first referenced
symbol                              in file
typeinfo for Operand                Expression_Tree.o
vtable for Operand                  Expression.o
```

through some googling and looking at similar questions I've found out that it is probably because of how I handle virtual functions (specifically constructors/destructor) in this

```
class Expression_Tree
{
 public:
  virtual double           evaluate() = 0;
  virtual std::string      get_postfix() const = 0;
  virtual std::string      get_infix() const = 0;
  virtual std::string      str() const = 0;
  virtual void             print(std::ostream&, int hopCount = 0) const = 0;
  virtual Expression_Tree* clone() const = 0;

  virtual ~Expression_Tree(){}
 protected:
  Expression_Tree() {}
  Expression_Tree(const Expression_Tree& o) = delete; 
  Expression_Tree(Expression_Tree&&) = default;
};
```

Does anyone see anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Self. Contained. Example. Please.

Comment: @KerrekSB I dont even know where to begin to create a self contained example of this.

Comment: Make sure you defined all pure virtual function in your subclasses. Depending on the compiler/linker, when a pure virtual function redefinition is missing, the vtable is silently skipped, only to be reported missing later.

Comment: the errors are about the `Operand` class - the code you showed has no mention of this class. As @KerrekSB said, please post some complete code that has the same issue you observe (start from your actual code, and cut out all irrelevant stuff).

Comment: The problem is a linker problem, so it's about the way you put the pieces together. It doesn't help to see only one piece. At least show your compiler invocation maybe?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your `Operand` declares a non-pure virtual, but doesn't define it; that often causes this error. But you forgot to post the class that's implicated by the error, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as some of you said in the Operand class, not it's base.

```
class Operand : public Expression_Tree
{
 public:
  Operand& operator=(const Operand&) = default;
  Operand& operator=(Operand&&) = default;
  // void print(std::ostream&, int hopCount = 0) const; <- this was the problem
  std::string get_postfix() const;
  std::string get_infix() const;
  ~Operand() = default;
  Operand(const Operand&) = default;
  Operand(Operand&&) = default;
 protected:
 Operand() 
   : Expression_Tree() {}
};
```

Once I removed the `void print()` everything worked out =)